# Logic nightmare in angular

Tags: angularjs, logic

I want to have a button appear when certain conditions are met but i cannot get my head around the logic.

To spell out the logic:

If the form GenericFormFields is valid AND :
 If a System's checkbox is ticked and the system's form is valid then Show Button, otherwise dont.  Not all systems need to be selected.

The problem I'm facing is when when a system isn't required, i dont know how to exclude that system from being evaluated, if System C isn't required and System A & B are checked, I want the expression to evaluate true:

```
ng-show="GenericFormFields.$valid && ( 
 (sysCheckBox.SystemSelected.a && SystemFormA.$valid) || 
 (sysCheckBox.SystemSelected.b && SystemFormB.$valid) ||
 (sysCheckBox.SystemSelected.c && SystemFormC.$valid)
)
```

I know the above wont work as it will evaluate true when just one system is selected and valid.  And in the same way the following wont evaluate to true if only two systems are selected because the && operator will want all systems to be checked and valid before evaluating to true:

```
ng-show="GenericFormFields.$valid && ( 
 (sysCheckBox.SystemSelected.a && SystemFormA.$valid) && 
 (sysCheckBox.SystemSelected.b && SystemFormB.$valid) &&
 (sysCheckBox.SystemSelected.c && SystemFormC.$valid)
)
```

And help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: So if I understood your question correctly have some checkboxes that are conditionally required? Could you post the relevant parts of your form?

Comment: No... the checkboxes are always there - its when a checkbox is clicked and it's related form is valid... then show a button... so if checkbox a and b are checked and their forms are valid then show the button.... the problem I'm having is that checkbox c is sitting there and because its not checked (and therefore false) its making the whole statement evaluate to false

Answer (score 2):

GenericFormFields.$valid &&

(!sysCheckBox.SystemSelected.a || SystemFormA.$valid) && (!sysCheckBox.SystemSelected.b || SystemFormB.$valid) && (!sysCheckBox.SystemSelected.b || SystemFormC.$valid)

Comment: Wow mike not sure how you think like that but it worked! Thank you! Mwarkkk

Answer (score 0):

First one should work, because it will be true when AT LEAST one of the conditions is true

Comment: but for my situation that doesnt work.  Say i only want to complete systems A and B, then after completing System A the button shows - but actually i only want it to show after System A & B have been completed.